# How to save an image's attribute id to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE - Sorry I tried to keep the code minimal, but looks like more detail is needed. I've created a non production jfiddle here with some notes to help explain what I'm trying to solve.

Hopefully this provides you with all details

http://jsfiddle.net/d86tm/5/

From looking at Google and SO nothing quite answers my answer...

After a user clicks an image I'd like to capture the attribute id assigned to the image and save it within a variable, something like

```
var friendRequestId = $(e.source).data("UserForBadge");
```

At the moment I have. But I'm not certain this is correct and its certainly returning an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: friendRequestId is not defined

Just looking for guidance/best practice example on how to complete this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.UserForBadge').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $('.UserForBadge').click(function(e) { 

    $(this).appendTo('friendRequestId');
        // Nothing to worry about this part at the mo/////////
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show us your html..? and what did you try to do with `$(this).appendTo('friendRequestId');` ..?

Comment: What is friendRequestId ? Specify class/id .using "." or "#"

Comment: Did you try `$(e.target).data("UserForBadge");` assuming the clicked element has that data.

Comment: I don't get it: your code doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question

Comment: I've updated the question and added a jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d86tm/5/ for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood by the question you wanted the id on the click of the image using jquery. Please find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XtYZ/)

The code snippet used is:

```
e.target.id
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly. your markup should be:

```
<img id="someId" onclick="imgClick(this)" />
```

and your js function:

```
function imgClick(sender){
var $img = $(this); //creates jQuery object from the DOM object 
var id = $img.attr('id'); // extracts the id attribute

//your code...
}
```

Comment: `onclik`? Are you sure?